# Comment « or » a-t-il changé semantiquement de « maintenant » à introduire une opposition ?

Tags: étymologie

> [[ Wiktionnaire : ]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/or#.C3.89tymologie) (Conjonction) [2.] De l’ancien français *ore*, *or*, « maintenant »,
>   [1.] du latin *hāc hōrā*, « à cette heure ».
>   Son emploi comme conjonction date du XIIe siècle.
>
> [[ Wiktionary : ]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/or#Conjunction_2) 
>       [3.] yet, however
>
> [[ Wordreference : ]](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/or) (introduit une opposition)      but, yet *conj*

J'ai déjà lu [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/or). Comment le sens 2 change-t-il sémantiquement au sens 3 ?

Comment: Par rapport à ta dernière phrase qui n'est peut-être pas très claire : l'évolution s'est faite du "sens 3" (adv) vers le "sens 2" (conj.) La phrase qui répond à ta question  dans le CNRTL est  *Adv. de l'articulation du discours, marque un point important dans l'enchaînement de la pensée, le passage d'une phrase à une autre (succession logique), cet emploi conduisant vers celui de conj. de coordination*.

Answer (score 1):

En ancien français *or* (du latin tardif *hora* → heure) signifiait « maintenant, à cette heure ». Ce sens est resté courant jusqu'au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle. Déjà dans cet usage ancien il commence à être utilisé pour structurer les articulations du discours. Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* signale l'emploi de *or du* avec le sens de « maintenant il s'agit de ».

> L'usage moderne de *or* conjonction s'est dégagé de *or* pris comme adverbe de l’articulation du discours, marquant un point important dans l'enchaînement de la pensée, le passage d'une phrase à l'autre (succession logique) : *or* a d'abord le sens d'« alors, donc » (1176-1181), « assurément, comme chacun sait » (1210), à « à la vérité en réalité » (1210). Au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle, il commence à être employé pour introduire un nouvel élément dans le récit, dans la suite d'un raisonnement (1580). (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey).

[Cette étude](http://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_2004_num_101_1_2571) sur l'emploi de *or* chez Agrippa d'Aubigné (écrivain du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle, période charnière dans l'évolution du mot), permet de mettre en relief les différents emplois et comment s'est fait le glissement de l'emploi temporel au *or* oppositif. Je me contente d'en reproduire textuellement la conclusion :

> En effet, placé en tête d'énoncé, il fonctionne comme connecteur coordonnant deux énoncés ou deux arguments. De plus, or provoque dans tous ces emplois un
>   effet d'arrêt. Pour *or* temporel qui renvoie au paramètre T<sub>0</sub> de son énonciation, cet arrêt permet de mettre en relation un avant et un après, ce dernier étant présenté comme le pôle actuel dans cette relation. Cet effet de suspension fait aussi sentir le souhait ou l'ordre, comme devant être immédiatement réalisé. Avec or oppositif, cet arrêt permet de revenir sur l'énoncé précédent afin de parvenir à la conclusion qui clôt le raisonnement. Par ailleurs, nous avons remarqué qu'au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle or conserve toujours une certaine relation avec son sens temporel étymologique. Les énoncés où *or* a une valeur intermédiaire entre l'adverbe temporel et la
>   conjonction prouvent le caractère instable de ce mot à cette époque. C'est cette ambiguïté qui a certainement favorisé le glissement sémantique d'abord et le changement catégoriel ensuite.

Je signale aussi [cet autre étude](http://lib.ugent.be/fulltxt/RUG01/001/786/635/RUG01-001786635_2012_0001_AC.pdf), « Or *vs* maintenant *en ancien
et en moyen français* », qui montre le processus par lequel des mots (*or* et *maintenant*), à l'origine lexicaux « désignant le moment de l’énonciation ou la proximité par rapport à ce moment, sont devenus peu à peu des mots grammaticaux assumant des fonctions logico-conjonctives. »